# What resistor (or indeed do I even need one)?

Tags: resistors, battery-charging

I have a device which charges a built-in AA battery. The factory AC/DC adapter outputs 200mA at 3v. This adapter has died one me.

I have another one lying around with the correct-size plug that can be set to output at 3v (measured 3.5v with my multimeter), but the current output is 1800mA. The device in question is not intelligent - it just sends all the current to the battery, and predictably, the battery gets insanely hot within a matter of minutes.

How can I reduce this current output to a max of ~200mA? I assume (likely wrongly) that I need to splice in a resistor on the positive wire. If so, what resistor do I need?

Comment: I'm hoping that's 1800 miliamps not 1800 amps! What sort of battery is it?

Comment: Oh yes sorry! 1800mA! It's a tagged AA batt - probably a cheapo NiCD or something.

Comment: The problem is that information on AC/DC adaptors are often far from reality. For example my Nokia phone charger states 3.6V 0.33A, but it actually gives 10 volts without load, and around 8 volts in normal working conditions when I measured it. The output of power supply always hugely depends on its construction type, whether it is regulated or not, how much is it soft or stiff. But the sole fact that it states 1800mA absolutely doesn't mean that the power supply somewhat forces the device to take 1800mA from it. That's nonsense.

Comment: Ah I see - thanks Al. Learning something new everyday. Anyways this is all a bit of fun (the device in question is $10, including adapter), but to my simple mind adding an in-line resistor might "fix" the problem (slow down the rate of charging) as a bit of a hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You talk about a single AA cell - about 1.5V, and a 3V adapter. So you need a resistor capable of dropping about 1.5V at 200ma - that would be 7.5 ohms. Power would be V*V/R or slightly over 0.25W.

I would use an 0.5 or 1W resistor for the purpose, and expect it to get quite warm. Exact resistor value won't be too critical - if I had a 10 ohm resistor handy it'd just take a little longer to charge.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I am seriously very new at all this, so do I just go into the electronics shop and ask for a "1W resistor"? I am not concerned about charging times by the way, so if it takes longer but cooler then that would be a better bet.

Comment: You need to ask for the right value and power, so 10 ohm 1 watt as an example.

Comment: Brian, be careful with these assumptions! 1.) The device probably wants to get 3 V, not 1.5 V, there is some charging mechanism is inside it and we know nothing about its circuitry. 2.) One or both of those AC/DC adaptors are probably unregulated and that's the main reason why they don't match and the battery gets very hot. The stronger one of them has got much more stiff output.

Comment: I just opened the thing up and I see a tiny PCB with some resistors on it, so it's not a straight circuit. The upshot is I will probably just buy a new one haha. Thanks all!

Comment: Al, you may have a point but there can't be much impedance between socket and battery, to deliver enough power to make the battery hot! The resistor is a reasonable simple approximation to the current limiting, nothing more.

Answer (score 3):

If the device only uses 200mA then it will only take 200mA. The maximum output current is the total the the supply can give. So there is no need for a resistor. A problem only arises when the devices current is higher than that of the supply. But this is not the case in your situation.

Comment: In most cases, yes, I understand that. However my little battery is getting ridiculously hot, and I think it's because the charging circuit inside the device for the built-in battery is just a straight terminal-to-terminal wire, which would mean the battery is taking all 1800mA and would explain why it is getting so hot. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed possible that the device relies on the current limiting implicit in the original charging adapter.

Comment: RC: I am affraid you write nonsense because you don't understand the basic principles: The current isn't always 1800mA - it depends mainly on the resistance of the device and quality of the power supply.

Comment: Al: I'm pretty sure I'm writing nonsense, but all I know is that the old charger doesn't make the battery hot, with a printed output of 200mA, and the new charger makes the battery boiling, with an output of 1800mA. I accept these numbers are imprecise and that I understand jack, but for the application of simply charging an AA cell, I think (??) I understand that I am giving the cell too much current and I need to get it down. I suspect Brian's answer above will get me close enough. :)

Comment: This answer is fundamentally mistaken, because it ignores the critical point that the load is a battery.  The current drawn by a charging battery will depend on the properties of the battery, its condition, and the applied voltage.  With an overvoltage, and a supply that is not limited to the required current, it will draw more current than it is supposed to to, potentially dangerously so.  Some means of current limitation will be required, though it's not clear if the details of the situation are well enough known for a resistor to be chosen as a limiter.

Answer (score 0):

1. No device (battery/AC adaptor/step-down transformer) can give 1800mA(1.8A) at 3.5v DC unless it is SMPS in computer which can give 2.5A at 5V. At its peak voltage (say 15v/18v/24v), your another device may give 1.8A but at 3.5v it will give very lesser current like 500mA/700mA.
2. As your device has built-in re-chargeable batteries, you must limit current otherwise, discharged batteries simply short the charging terminals logically, thus eating up all the current which makes batteries hot in minutes.
3. you must add current limiting resistor in series before connecting the batteries to your new device's terminals.
4. Calculate (Ohm's Law): I = V/R (I=charging (required) current in Amps, V=Supply Voltage, R= Series Resistance in Ohms); convert it into : R = V/I = 3.5V/0.2A(200mA) = 17.5 Ohms next nearest resister you can get is 19 Ohms, 1W resistor.
5. if your battery capacity is 500mA, approximately it will take (500/150mA due to 19 Ohm resistor)3.5 hours to full-charge. divide cell capacity by charging current, result is charging time in hours.

Comment: "No device (battery/AC adaptor/step-down transformer) can give 1800mA(1.8A) at 3.5v DC unless it is SMPS in computer which can give 2.5A at 5V." I built a 5V, 2.5A switching power supply in the space of a few square inches. Power supply technology has advanced quite a bit in the past 20 years.

Comment: As Ignacio has noted, this answer is fundamentally flawed, both in its statement about "No device..." and in assuming that a charging battery is an Ohmic device.